# MIDI - Continous control of pitch outside the standard pitch bend range?

Tags: midi

After I send a note on message I can control the pitch of a note within a ±2 semitone range using the pitch bend channel command.

How can I continuously update a pitch of a note outside of the normal pitch bend range without retriggering the note (i.e. sending another note on message with the new pitch?)

In other words the current note is still sounding after a note on message and its envelope has not reached the end of its release stage. I would like to change the pitch outside the pitch bend range, preferably anywhere within the audible frequency range.

Answer (score 0):

Does your actual synth (or software synth, whichever you happen to be using) allow you to set a wider range than ±2 semitones? MIDI itself only gives you 16,384 gradiations[*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_wheel) for your pitch bend, so you can't just go setting pitch bend to 16,385. Instead you have to tell the synth itself to interperate 16,384† to be a higher or lower pitch.

†*Note: off by one, I know. I'm simplifying here, technically 16,384 would be 16,383*

Comment: What is one gradiation equal to?  I can then set the note on to the a frequency at the middle of the entire range and bend up and down from there.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work that way. If your synth is set to a ±2 semitone range (which is a range of 2 semitones higher and lower) then each gradient will be: 4 divided by 16,384. If you set your synth to ± one octave (12 semitones x 2) than each gradient will be: 24 divided by 16,384. If you set your synth to ± two octaves (24 semitones x 2) than each gradient will be: 48 divided by 16,384.  And so on ...

Comment: So how does one achieve continuous changes in pitch over the range of [20, 20,000] Hz?

Comment: Hang on :) I'm googling for the number of Octaves between 20 - 22000 now ...

Comment: 10 octaves. So the finest precision you could get (unless you are using software which allows you to use floating point numbers) would be: ±5 octaves (60 semitones x 2). So 120 divided by 16,384.

Comment: So the finest change you could make is 0.00734 / semitone. If this is still audible (I'm not sure if it is or not, I haven't tested) then I don't have a quick answer for you. Maybe MIDI is the wrong tool for the job, if you require more smoothness than this.

Comment: If you have no other choice than to use MIDI, enabling "Portamento" might be an alternate method (you could then slide between the lowest and highest note) - you would have very limited control over timing though (over of the rate of change).

Comment: MIDI is my only option at the moment.  The Portamento controller on/off is 65 but it doesn't seem to affect the Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth.  Is the MSB 0 for off >0 for on?

Comment: Is that a DirectX thing? I wouldn't know much about it. Try playing two notes at the same time though, that's the kind of portamento you want (assuming it's not a polyphonic patch).

Comment: Two notes at the same time do not respond to portamento.

Comment: There must be a way to increase the pitch bend range?

Comment: Hmmm, that is a good, but different, question. You should re-post or revise this as "How to increase the pitch bend range for the Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth beyond ±2 semitones"

Comment: Also "There must be a way" is not necessarily the case. MIDI is an ancient spec, and the DirectX synth in Windows is based on code from an ancient Roland SoundCanvas (I used one of these, back in the day!) There could well be limitations.

Comment: There is a way!  I have found the answer extending the pitch bend range using a registered parameter number of (0, 0)

Comment: A bit of coding later and it seems to work.  I must now work out the alogrithm to calculate the exact range and LSB and MSB required for each frequency.  Shouldn't be too hard given that it is now possible and the Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth (as do all synths that conform to the MIDI standard) responds to this message. :)

Comment: Well done, user1423893 :) Happy you're sorted

Comment: @user1423893 If you've figured it out, then why not share your solution with the rest of us as an actual "Answer" to your own question?  It's allowed. :)